# A clean and efficient way to update cells in pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a cleaner way to achieve the following:

I have a DataFrame with certain columns that I want to update if new information arrives. This "new information" in for of a pandas `DataFrame` (from a CSV file) can have more or less rows, however, I am only interested in adding

#### Original DataFrame

[image]

#### DataFrame with new information

[image]

(Note the missing name "`c`" here and the change in "status" for name "`a`")

Now, I wrote the following "inconvenient" code to update the original DataFrame with the new information

#### Updating the "status" column based on the "name" column

```
for idx,row in df_base.iterrows():
    if not df_upd[df_upd['name'] == row['name']].empty:
        df_base.loc[idx, 'status'] = df_upd.loc[df_upd['name'] == row['name'], 'status'].values
```

[image]

It achieves exactly what I want, but it just does neither look nice nor efficient, and I hope that there might be a cleaner way. I tried the `pd.merge` method, however, the problem is that it would be adding new columns instead of "updating" the cells in that column.

```
pd.merge(left=df_base, right=df_upd, on=['name'], how='left')
```

[image]

I am looking forward to your tips and ideas.

Comment: If `name` is the column you want to use to "identify" rows, can you make that the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `set_index("name")` and then call [`.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
>>> df_base = df_base.set_index("name")
>>> df_upd = df_upd.set_index("name")
>>> df_base.update(df_upd)
>>> df_base
      status
name        
a          0
b          1
c          0
d          1
```

More generally, you can set the index to whatever seems appropriate, update, and then reset as needed.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Sorry, didn't know about the `update` function